# to find date difference in mongodb query in codeigniter

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to get difference between a date that I found from the database and the other is the current date both are in the same format(example - `2018-06-09 11:02:49`).

How can I find the difference between two dates in days format in CodeIgniter?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1):

Try  this

```
$date1 = date_create("2018-06-09 11:02:49");
$date2 = date_create("2018-06-08 11:02:49");
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
echo $diff->format("%a day");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `PHP 5.3` >, this is by far the most accurate way of calculating the difference:

```
$earlier = new DateTime("2018-05-20 11:02:49");
$later = new DateTime("2018-06-11 11:02:49");

$diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a day(s)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you :

***First*** way : you can use CI `date_helper's` `timespan` method

```
$expired_date = '2018-06-09 11:02:49';
$post_date = strtotime($expired_date);
$now = time();
$units =1;
echo timespan($post_date, $now, $units);
```

Ouptput :

```
2 Days
```

***Second*** way use core php `date_diff()` method

working demo : https://eval.in/1018721

```
//$expired_date = $query->row()->expired_at;
$expired_date = '2018-06-09 11:02:49';
$expired_date = date_create($expired_date);
$cdate = date_create('now');
$interval = date_diff($expired_date,$cdate);

//echo $interval->format('%a').PHP_EOL;
echo $interval->d;
```

Output :

```
2
```

CI reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php